# Wordpress Custom post type + metabox doesn't save data

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

When I save post, data in metabox aren't saved in database...where is the bug ?

My code is here at: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jezygsuL).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have declared your `$rest_custom_meta_fields` array inside `restaurant_data_form` function and trying to use it in `save_restaurant_custom_meta` function, in this case the array is out of the function scope so `foreach ($rest_custom_meta_fields as $field)` is not working.

To overcome this problem you can keep the array out of your `restaurant_data_form`, just declare the `array` right before the `restaurant_data_form` function like

```
$rest_custom_meta_fields = array(  
    array(  
        'label'=> 'Address',  
        'desc'  => 'Plugin use it to get map',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'text_address',  
        'type'  => 'text'  
    ),
    ...
);
```

And in your `restaurant_data_form` function

```
function restaurant_data_form()
{
    $prefix = 'rest_';
    global $post, $rest_custom_meta_fields;
    // ...
}
```

So it should look something like this (the array is in the global scope)

```
$rest_custom_meta_fields = array( 
    array(...),
    ...
);
function restaurant_data_form()
{
    $prefix = 'rest_';
    global $post, $rest_custom_meta_fields;
    // ...
}
```

I hope this will solve the problem. Also at the end of your code you have used

```
echo add_action('save_post', 'save_restaurant_custom_meta');
```

Remove the `echo` from the beginning of the `add_action(...)` statement.